# How to retrieve selected item's id from listbox which is bound to datatable?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a listbox which I bound to `Datable` [`employee`] where listbox shows employee name.

How can I get the selected item's `id` like `employee_id` from database?

Here is my part if code

**XAML-**

```
ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="employee_name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16.362,108.171,0,44.541" Name="lstbxEmloyee" Width="333.603" SelectionChanged="lstbxEmployee_SelectionChanged"
```

**.cs**

```
EmployeeData _employeeData = new EmployeeData();

_employeeData.GetEmployeeName();

lstbxEmloyee.ItemsSource = _employeeData._dataTable.DefaultView;
```

I want to fetch `employee_id` for selected `employee_name` from listbox

please help me out

and Thank u....

Comment: In `SelectionChanged` event get the SelectedItem and cast it to your datatype and then iterate over the items

Comment: @praveen but listbox contains only name from datatable, i want to fetch employee_id for selected employee_name...

Comment: Is your datatable containing id

Comment: @Arshad yes employee_id

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         // you can bind your data as per your requirement
        lstbxEmloyee.ItemsSource = GetTable().DefaultView; 
    }

    private void lstbxEmloyee_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      DataRow dr=((DataRowView) (lstbxEmloyee.SelectedItem)).Row;
      int Emp_id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["employee_ID"]);
      MessageBox.Show(Emp_id.ToString());
    }

    DataTable GetTable()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("employee_ID", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("employee_name", typeof(string));        

        table.Rows.Add(1,"David");
        table.Rows.Add(2,"Sam");
        table.Rows.Add(3,"Christoff");
        table.Rows.Add(4, "Janet");
        table.Rows.Add(5, "Melanie");

        return table;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes i did it.I figured out solution for my question 
I made changes in code as below
  **XAML-**
  ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="employee_name" **SelectedValuePath="employee_id"** HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16.362,108.171,0,44.541" Name="lstbxEmloyee" Width="333.603" SelectionChanged="lstbxEmployee_SelectionChanged"

**.cs**
string _selectedProject = lstbxProjects.SelectedItem.ToString();

It's binding between "SelectedValuePath" and "SelectedValue"
where-
 SelectedValuePath - to refer which column from datatable
 SelectedValue- gives value from